# Fragment Communication - selecting tabs and running methods in other tabs (Fragments)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have implemented a tabbed Action bar using android fragments (not from the support package).  I have a button on one of the tabs which when pressed calls a method in the parent activity using a interface.

The method in the parent activity function is to change the selected tab (fragment) and call a method in that tab.

I have an interface which allows one of the fragments to call this method in the parent activity

```
@Override
public void onChangeTabButtonSelected(String billingID)
{
    int position = 1;  // Selects 2nd Tab
    getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        ((fragmentTabSearchClients) searchClientsTab).getClients(billingID);

}
```

This works fine and the tab is changed and the method is called but it appears the fragment lifecycle has not been initiated correctly has the method called `getClients` uses `getView()' which always returns null.

In the parent class is there a way to initialise the tab before calling a method on the tab?

Comment: have you use pager inside? if yes than i think it is creating problem.i am not conform about it.i working around your problem,if i get success then i will back to you.

Comment: Thanks, for the query. No I'm not using a pager inside.  Just a single button on one Tab that calls onChangeTabButtonSelected() in the parent class.

Comment: getClients() method is from your interface,may i right?

Comment: onChangeTabButtonSelected() is the implementation of the interface between the Fragment and the Fragment Container (in this case a standard Activity). getClients() is just a public method in the fragment (fragmentTabSearchClients) I want to call.

Comment: read more on "handling the fragment lifecycle" from docs. Maybe you can use the backstack and use "addToBackStack" for your frag/view that does not restore proper. From the backStack, the view owned by fragment will be there with good reference.